# how to pass reference of a pointer with parallelism?

Tags: pointers, go, parallel-processing

I'm writing a bot to run some commands in parallel and at the same time run the bots in parallel, but I'm having trouble starting and pausing functions.

Below I'll leave an example I set up. It was expected that one of the bots would continue to run and others would stop, but all would end up running.

Could someone explain to me why, when using the `startbot()` command, it does not get bool?

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "time"
)

type botBase struct {
    isEnabled bool
}

func (b *botBase) startFunctionX() {
    b.isEnabled = true
}

func (b *botBase) pauseFunctionX() {
    b.isEnabled = false
}

func (b botBase) runCommandX() {
    for {
        if b.isEnabled {
            log.Print("running...")
        } else {
            log.Print("paused...")
        }
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }
}

type bot struct {
    botBase
    //other stuffs
}

func (b bot) runAllCommands() {
    go b.runCommandX()

    //wait parallels commands
    for{
        time.Sleep(10 * time.Hour)
    }
}

type bots struct {
    List []bot
}

func (b *bots) loadListDB() {
    b1 := bot{}
    b1.isEnabled = false
    b2 := bot{}
    b2.isEnabled = false
    b.List = []bot{b1, b2}
}

var myBots bots

func main() {
    myBots.loadListDB()
    for _, b := range myBots.List {
        b.startFunctionX()
        go b.runAllCommands()
    }

    //control stop and start bots
    log.Print("expected true = ", myBots.List[0].isEnabled)
    myBots.List[0].pauseFunctionX()
    log.Print("expected false = ", myBots.List[0].isEnabled)


    //wait bots parallels
    for {
        time.Sleep(10 * time.Hour)
    }
}
```

Comment: You are stopping a *copy* of your bot. You probably meant to make a list of pointer to bot, `[]*bot`. You are also mixing pointer receivers and non-pointer receivers in the methods. Don't do that; [it causes confusion](https://golang.org/doc/faq#methods_on_values_or_pointers). Finally, you have to synchronize access to the `isEnabled` field. Reading and writing values concurrently is unsafe. `go build -race` can point out some concurrency bugs like this one.

Comment: about mixing methods, the three method pointers used need to change the receiver. What's wrong with that? I did not understand.

Comment: `runCommandX` doesn't have a pointer receiver, but all the other methods do. That makes the method set complicated for no reason. It's in the FAQ I linked above: "Next is consistency. If some of the methods of the type must have pointer receivers, the rest should too, so the method set is consistent regardless of how the type is used. See the section on method sets for details."

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience and explanation. I read the link you sent, but since my English is bad I did not understand correctly. Everything worked out now. Will you make a correct answer to the mark or can I mark that of Gal Ben-Haim

Comment: Gal's answer is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the range statement returns the value of a bot which is then changed so you're actually checking a different bot.. work with references -

```
for i := range myBots.List {
    b := &myBots.List[i]
    b.startFunctionX()
    go b.runAllCommands()
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/1V8tKx431QJ